# Why Can't I Drag and Drop Objects from the Library to the Canvas in Xcode 15 using SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, xcode15

The canvas appears to be read-only... I can only drag and drop objects (Views & Modifiers & so on) from the Library onto the code itself. I'm doing a class on udemy where the instructor is literally dragging and dropping objects onto the canvas and it auto-updates the code and the canvas at the same time. She's using an older version of Xcode, however. Why did Apple remove this functionality? Or am I missing a setting somewhere? Even when I drag, say, a button into the code, I can't even drag and move the button around on the canvas, it's just unclickable.

Comment: I think this feature is indeed removed. “Why did Apple remove this functionality?” is not a very useful or clear question. What kind of answers are you looking for?

Comment: Lol, sorry, I just needed to know whether or not they indeed removed the feature. Thanks!

Comment: Frustrating. The current Xcode 15 docs clearly say, "click the Library button (+) in the toolbar to open the library, then drag user interface elements from the library to either the canvas or source code."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Apple confirmed that this feature was removed in Xcode 15.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/746483