# Xcode 15.0.1 SwiftUI preview is not editable anymore?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have updated my Xcode to **15.0.1** and noticed that I could not drag anything (button, label, etc) from the library to preview canvas like in the past. I have tested it on both **'Live'** and **'Selectable'** modes. Is this another Xcode bug or did they just remove that feature and the preview canvases are not editable directly?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77385856/5133585 I think they simply removed this feature. You can still drag views onto the code editor though.